R- Adding Centroids to Texture Points on Texture Triangle
I have a soil texture data set. I made a soil texture triangle representing soil texture from different projects.
I want to add a centroid to the texture triangle, but only for projects with different textures. I want to show on a plot that even with different textures in one single project they belong to the same project.
Is it possible to do this using ggplot2 or is there a specific package that can do it?
Here is what I tried with the ggplot2 code. I tried two versions of plotting the centroids on a soil texture triangle. I was able to add those centroids, but in my trial Version 1, not all projects with different textures have centroids.  While in my trial Version 2, altogether different projects have centroids. I want all projects with different textures to have centroids and want all of them to be shown in the plot.
`# Plotting the soil texture triangle

theme_set(theme_bw())
p \<-filtered_soil_triangle  %\>%
ggtern(aes(
x = SAND,
y = CLAY,
z = SILT,
color = Project )) +
geom_point(size = ifelse(is.na(filtered_soil_triangle $Project), 0, 6)) +
theme_showarrows() +
labs(yarrow = "Clay (%)",
zarrow = "Silt (%)",
xarrow = "Sand(%)",
color = "Project") +
scale_color_paletteer_d("rcartocolor::Safe") +  # Use the Safe color palette
theme_clockwise()+
theme(
legend.title = element_text(size = 14),  # Increase legend title size
legend.text = element_text(size = 12)     # Increase legend text size
)`


`# Trial Version 1

## Add arrows connecting points with the same Project and different map_texture

### Create a new data frame for segments

segments_data \<- filtered_soil_triangle %\>%
group_by(Project, map_texture) %\>%
arrange(SAND, CLAY, SILT) %\>%  
mutate(next_SAND = lead(SAND),
next_CLAY = lead(CLAY),
next_SILT = lead(SILT)) %\>%
filter(!is.na(next_SAND))

### Add segments to the plot

p + geom_segment(data = segments_data,
aes(x = SAND, y = CLAY, z = SILT,
xend = next_SAND, yend = next_CLAY, zend = next_SILT),
arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.01, "inches")),
color = "black",
linewidth = 0.5)`  

Version 1
`# Trial Version 2

## Add arrows connecting points with the same Project and different map_texture

### Create a new data frame for segments

segments_data \<- filtered_soil_triangle %\>%
group_by(Project) %\>%
arrange(SAND, CLAY, SILT) %\>%  
mutate(next_SAND = lead(SAND),
next_CLAY = lead(CLAY),
next_SILT = lead(SILT),
next_map_texture = lead(map_texture)) %\>%
filter(!is.na(next_SAND) & map_texture != next_map_texture)

### Add segments to the plot

p + geom_segment(data = segments_data,
aes(x = SAND, y = CLAY, z = SILT,
xend = next_SAND, yend = next_CLAY, zend = next_SILT),
arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.01, "inches")),
color = "black",
linewidth = 0.5)  # Use line width instead of size`

Version 2

Your plots are quite detailed. What was the process that led to filtered_soil_triangle and perhaps some links to representative data?

Soil enthusiasm here! Are you talking about the centroid of the actual USDA classes? Or the centroid/average of your data within a class? If so, you can try to categorize your data with an addtionnal column of your  data.frame. Take a look at the soiltexture package.

Is there a relation between centroids and segments?  As Chris said, we don't know if you have a problems with your dataset, or with the plot

I think the 'centroids and segments` are meant to convey dissimilar soil constituents united by 'Project(s)', so not a typical use of 'centroid', here a marker for segment end points. Well, perhaps. Or problem with how dataset was filtered to connect to projects.

@Chris, I used the ggtern package. I had a lot of columns with different data. The ggtern package somehow allows me to read only columns with SAND, SILT, and CLAY. So, I had to filter only the columns that I wanted to show on the plot with project names and texture. Here are some links I used for help 1 [2] (https://saryace.github.io/flipbook_soiltexture_en/#61)

@VinceGreg: I think I just want the centroid of my data. I just want to show that different textures belong to one single project. For example, I have five different textures for Project Oregon State.

I feel like just as @Chris mentioned maybe the centroid is not meant for this relationship for projects.

I think you can summarise() sand/clay/silt within a project (with an average) in a second dataset, and with a second geom_point() represent both . I could make an exemple/answer, but I think that you should edit your answer first.
Because: " I want to add a centroid to the texture triangle, but only for projects with different textures."
should become "I want to add the project-average to the texture triangle ,but only for projects with multiples sites  "  ,   if I understand correctly

So, if a Project with multiple 'sites' predominated to 'SILT'  with all those sites taken together, it's  'centroid' would be toward right lower corner, balanced constituents to the center, 'SAND' and 'CLAY' to their respective corners on a purely % relative, not spatial. scale. Which I think takes us back to ggtern, data under consideration, and how the weighting was arrived. And I've said as much as I know, and rely on @VinceGreg.

The question need majors clarifications; I don't think that a "centroid" is required as a summary indicator. However, if the average per project is a valid indicator, here is a reprex to do it with ggplot (tidyverse) and ggtern.   You can group_by(Project), summarise() , and filter()-out the projects with a single site. With some aesthetic ajustments, the average and site can be represented.
Edit: if a centroid is really needed, sf::st_centroid() might be usefull. I think that an average do the work, let me know otherwise.
Edit: it seems doable to use st_centroid() (see second example), however I removed the geometry before plotting in ggtern,
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtern)

# Data per site
soil_texture_df <- data.frame(SAND=c(12, 20, 80),
                              SILT=c(50, 48, 5)) |> 
  mutate(CLAY = 100 - SAND - SILT) |> 
  mutate(Project = c("A","A","B"))

#Summarise per project
by_project <- soil_texture_df |>  group_by(Project) |> 
  summarise( across(SAND:CLAY, mean), n = n()) |> 
  filter(n>1)
  
by_project   |> 
  ggtern(aes(
    x = SAND,    y = CLAY,    z = SILT, color = Project )) +
  geom_point( alpha = 0.5, aes(size ="Project average"))+ 
  geom_point( alpha = 1, data = soil_texture_df, aes(size ="Site")) +
  scale_size_manual( values = c("Site"=2 ,"Project average" =6 ) )


Created on 2024-12-19 with reprex v2.1.0
(Edit with centroid)
(I didn't removed the project with a single site)
project_centroid = soil_texture_df %>%
  st_as_sf(coords =c("SAND","SILT","CLAY"), dim ="XYZ", remove =FALSE) %>%
  group_by(Project) %>%
  summarise(do_union = FALSE) %>%
  st_cast("MULTIPOINT") %>% st_centroid() %>%
  mutate(SAND = sf::st_coordinates(.)[,1],
                SILT = sf::st_coordinates(.)[,2]) %>%
  mutate(CLAY = 100 - SAND - SILT) %>%
  st_drop_geometry()

project_centroid  %>%
  ggtern(aes(
    x = SAND,    y = CLAY,    z = SILT, color = Project )) +
  geom_point( alpha = 0.5, aes(size ="Project average"))+
  geom_point( alpha = 1, data = soil_texture_df, aes(size ="Site")) +
  scale_size_manual( values = c("Site"=2 ,"Project average" =6 ) )


Created on 2024-12-19 with reprex v2.0.2

This looks to be an effective template to treat the % scale and their dispersal around the chosen c('mean', 'median'). I don't see how, within the context of the % based scale that an sf::st_centroid might be employed except in a different plot paradigm (where I take the above to be representative of soil texture plots among soil researchers/enthusiasts).

I added an example with sf::st_centroid. The goal was just to take advantage of the sf capacities to evaluate the centroid of a mulitpoint feature (Or should it be a convex polygon?). I don't know if there is a better way to represent all 3 components (Sand, Silt, Clay) as sf coordinates, however two of them are enough seems they add up to 100%

Actually improves the visual as 'site' and 'B' were similar size previous. Anyway, all good. sf::Jitter?

Thanks, @VinceGreg I will try with your code and let you know if it works.
